# Moving and rename a file by its directory name

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I want to create a .bat file that moves an excel file to specific directory and rename the excel as its folder name.

**UPDATE:**

The idea of all this is that I want to copy an file, named below "fisier general.xls" to multiple folders with different names such as "CITY MALL" folder.
Now I use the code below, only to copy the file but I realised that the file has to be named exactly as the directory where the excel file was copied in.

```
copy C:\"Documents and Settings"\rnic\"My Documents"\Razvan\"Rapoarte Aringhe"\"IOAN - Exceptii planograme"\"Fisier general.xls" C:\"Documents and Settings"\rnic\"My Documents"\Razvan\"Rapoarte Aringhe"\"IOAN - Exceptii planograme"\"Mega Image"\"CITY MALL"
```

maybe you can help me with this.. the `fisier general.xls` should be renamed as `CITY MALL.xls`

Comment: Can you elaborate what you're trying to achieve? Initial folder structure and Expected end result folder structure would be nice to have.

Answer (score 0):

This .bat will go through folders starting with %def% and if there is a file named oldname.xlsx,
then it'll move it to first subfolder it finds.

```
@echo off

set fn=oldname
set ext=.xlsx
set def=c:\

for /R %def% %%i in (.) do ( 
 if exist "%%~di%%~pi%fn%%ext%" (
  for /D %%d in ("%%~di%%~pi*") do (
        move "%%~di%%~pi%fn%%ext%" "%%d\%%~nd%ext%"
  )
 )
)
```

Comment: hi, the problem is not solved, I don't know how it works, so if you want to help me, here's the code that i use `copy C:\"Documents and Settings"\rnic\"My Documents"\Razvan\"Rapoarte Aringhe"\"IOAN - Exceptii planograme"\"Fisier general.xls" C:\"Documents and Settings"\rnic\"My Documents"\Razvan\"Rapoarte Aringhe"\"IOAN - Exceptii planograme"\"Mega Image"\"CITY MALL" ` maybe you can help me with this.. the `fisier general.xls` should be renamed as `CITY MALL.xls`

Comment: plesase put your code to your question, it is unreadable in the comment box.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need as many quotes as you are using in your current batch file.
Also, you can rename the file on the copy command.

> copy "C:\Documents and Settings\rnic\My Documents\Razvan\Rapoarte Aringhe\IOAN - Exceptii planograme\Fisier general.xls" "C:\Documents and Settings\rnic\My Documents\Razvan\Rapoarte Aringhe\IOAN - Exceptii planograme\Mega Image\CITY MALL\CITY HALL.xls"

if you wanted this in a batch file where you could supply the file name, I would use make a batch file containing:

> copy "C:\Documents and Settings\rnic\My Documents\Razvan\Rapoarte Aringhe\IOAN - Exceptii planograme\Fisier general.xls" "C:\Documents and Settings\rnic\My Documents\Razvan\Rapoarte Aringhe\IOAN - Exceptii planograme\Mega Image\%~1\%~1.xls"

and call the batch file using `MyBatchFile "The Folder Name"`